# Why was the game designer actor replaced in the show "Level Up"?

Tags: casting, level-up

On the Cartoon Network show [*Level Up*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_Up_(U.S._TV_series)) they changed the actor playing Max Ross, the creator of the *Conqueror of All Worlds* game. In the movie he was one guy and now for the series he is someone else.

It seemed that the network green lit the series early on because it's been getting announced ever since the movie was first aired. So why was this one actor replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric Andre (who played Max in the movie) is a series regular on the upcoming show Don't Trust The B***h in Apartment 23. Sometimes when a TV movie is shot ahead of a series, actors only sign contracts for the one appearance. In the interim they'll get other jobs (which probably pay far better) that have contracts that are more strict and don't allow for the time to work on more than one series.

He also has his own Adult Swim show coming out this summer, so he's pretty busy. :D

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply because Eric André's contract was not renewed. This might be due to various reasons, and I won't try to rely on gossip to answer why.

Eric André, who played Max Ross in the film, will not be returning for the series. Lonny Ross will be replacing Eric André's character in the series as well.